# aftet sending btc with bitcoin core can i exit after wards?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoincore-gui

I have bitcoin core installed on windows with full node running.

If I send bitcoin do I need to wait its confirmation before exiting bitcoin core ? can I exit in seconds afterward will it be confirmed ?

Answer (score 1):

Once successfully broadcast, your transaction will be entered into the mempools of other nodes on the network, and it will eventually be confirmed in a block when it's fee-rate becomes competitive. This will occur whether or not you keep your wallet/node online in the meantime. So once your transaction is broadcast to the network you can exit the program without any issue.

Comment: Thank you for reply. how long broadcasting transaction takes ? and how can i confirm it ?

Comment: confirm that it was broadcasted how can i check.